# How to put Header in web api help page Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-helppages

I hit one api call on the server in which i pass header Content-type.

Now on the web api help page Documentation want to show that this Headers are passed when web api call is made

Put below code for Documentation on the method.

but how to pass headers in this xml Documnet?

```
    /// <summary>
    ///Register the User with Device Info Which are Coming From Facebook and Twitter 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="device">Device Info from which the user is logged in</param>
    /// <author>Dhruti Shah</author>
    /// <returns>Device</returns>
```